# Google webmaster duplicate url issue with /page/01 /page/400

Tags: permalinks

I am at the intermediate level in WordPress development. I am facing a problem with URLs. Google webmaster is showing me duplicate pages and error pages URLs like `www.mywebsite.com/page/01` to `www.mywebsite.com/page/400`. When I type `www.mywebsite.com/page/01`, it redirects me another page with posts and pagination. I tried editing the `.htaccess` to disable this but to no avail. I don't know how to search this problem via google and I need a solution on how can I disable these types of URLs.

Comment: Google Search Console does not update immediately and, possibly,  shows you old data. Use Screaming Frog or similar to find duplicates.

Comment: @MaxYudin dude i agree with u but i need solution for this how to prevent these types of urls

Comment: It's impossible to divine how the pagination is arranged. We need some relevant code.

Comment: this issue is related to https://wordpress.org/support/topic/weird-url-problem-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone find this helpful.

i research and find solution using .htaccess rules to solve these errors maybe it is temporary
but it fixed my problem. i redirect all these type of errors to home page using below code:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 /page/[0-9]{2,} http://example.com
        RedirectMatch 301 /page[0-9]{2,} http://example.com
</IfModule>
```